# Get data from Dictionary for Table

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsdictionary, watchkit

I have a WatchKit `table` that I need populated with the data I received (from iOS to WatchKit).  I can't figure out **how to unwrap the data in the `Dictionary` for use in the `table`**.

I have the data in the WatchKit **`InterfaceController`.swift**

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : AnyObject]) {

    let dic3 = userInfo["TColor"] as? String
    let dic4 = userInfo["Match"] as? String

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        //
    }
}
```

WatchKit **`Event`.swift** (subclass of main object)

```
class Event {

var eventTColor:String
var eventMatch:String

init(dataDictionary:Dictionary<String,String>) {
    eventTColor = dataDictionary["TColor"]!
    eventMatch = dataDictionary["Match"]!
}

class func newEvent(dataDictionary:Dictionary<String,String>) -> Event {
    return Event(dataDictionary: dataDictionary)
}

class func eventsList() -> [Event] {

    var array = [Event]()
    let dataPath = // Not sure what to do here

    let data = // Not sure what to do here either

    for e in data as! [Dictionary<String, String>] {
        let event = Event(dataDictionary: e)
        array.append(event)
    }

    return array
}

}
```

I can't figure out what to do in the piece of the function `class func eventsList() -> [Event]` that I'm missing.

**I need to get the information from the `Dictionary` I received in `didReceiveUserInfo`.**

Or maybe there's some better/other way to solve this?  Will post any extra code as needed.

**EDIT:** This is what I'm trying for `didFInishUserInfoTransfer` so far

```
func session(session: WCSession, didFinishUserInfoTransfer userInfoTransfer: WCSessionUserInfoTransfer, error: NSError?) {
        if let someError = error {
            print("error on didFinishUserInfoTransfer: %@", someError)
        } else {
            let eventsList = Event.eventsListFromValues(receivedData)
            NSLog("Events List: %@", eventsList)

        }
    }
```

func doTable() {

```
eventsListSO = Event.eventsListFromValues(receivedData)
rowTable.setNumberOfRows(eventsListSO.count, withRowType: "rows")
NSLog("Row count: %@", eventsListSO.count)

for var i = 0; i < self.rowTable.numberOfRows; i++ {
    let row = rowTable.rowControllerAtIndex(i) as? TableRowController
    print("Row")
    for eventm in eventsListSO {
        row!.mLabel.setText(eventm.eventMatch)
        NSLog("SetupTableM: %@", eventm.eventMatch)
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little hard to tell from the code posted, but it looks like your `InterfaceController` is receiving the data for a single event in the form of two `String` values in the `userInfo` dictionary parameter.  Presumably if you are expecting a list, this method is getting called multiple times.

If the above is true, it would probably make sense to create a `var` property in `InterfaceController` of type `Array<Dictionary<String,String>>` (or the equivalent `[[String : String]]`, which I personally find less readable), like so:

```
var receivedData = Array<Dictionary<String, String>>()
```

Then in your implementation of `session:didReceiveUserInfo:` you would append the content to the `receivedData` property, like so:

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if let tColorValue = userInfo["TColor"] as? String, let matchValue = userInfo["Match"] as? String {
        receivedData.append(["TColor": tColorValue, "Match": matchValue])
    }
    else {
        // Appropriate error handling here
    }
}
```

Your `eventsList` method would then need to be changed to accept your `Dictionary` of values and process it, perhaps like so:

```
class func eventsListFromValues(values: Array<Dictionary<String, String>>) -> Array<Event> {
    var array = Array<Event>()

    for eventValues in values {
        let event = Event(dataDictionary: eventValues)
        array.append(event)
    }

    return array
}
```

With these things in place you now have a collection of your data values, and you would need to determine when it is an appropriate time to construct your `Array` of `Event` objects.  Perhaps after every call to `session:didReceiveUserInfo:` with some code like so:

```
let eventsList = Event.eventsListFromValues(receivedData)
for event in eventList {
  // Do something with the events list (i.e., use event.eventTColor and event.eventMatch)
}
```

Obviously I based this answer on some assumptions about what's going on, so it may not be correct for exactly what you've got going on, but hopefully will get you going in the right direction.  Also, I wrote this code without a compiler handy, so it may need some minor tweaks.

Comment: Wow this is an amazingly good answer, so thank you!  Question: on `eventsListFromValues`, I get an error on the `let event = Event(dataDictionary: e)` line because I never use `e`, and I'm sure you realized that and were assuming I could flesh it out but I'm stuck on where to go exactly with that.  Can you let me know where you were going with that since I'm not getting it somehow.  Thanks!

Comment: (Also, yes you're correct on your assumptions from what I can tell!)

Comment: What is the error exactly?  It would be strange for it to be telling you that you weren't using e on a line where you were using it.

Comment: I think on that line I need to use `let event = Event(dataDictionary: eventValues)` instead of `let event = Event(dataDictionary: e)` if that sounds right to you?

Comment: Yes, that would be correct.  I typed that code without using Xcode, so my mistake.  I'll update it for posterity.

Comment: If I was a little more skilled I would have known for sure what it was supposed to mean, but I'm still getting better so thats why I needed to check first.  Your answer was awesome and you did mention you didn't do it in a compiler, so that was helpful.

Comment: Quick question, re: "...appropriate time to construct your Array of Event objects (perhaps after every call to session:didReceiveUserInfo: or after some indication that you've received everything)" I see what you are saying with it calling `didReceiveUserInfo:` a few times based on the data its grabbing, and to make sure its over to construct the array, what do you suggest there to check and then also construct the array?

Comment: I'm actually not familiar with `WCSession`, but looking at the documentation for `WCSessionDelegate` (which is where that `session:didReceiveUserInfo:` method comes from), I do see a `session:didFinishUserInfoTransfer:error:` method.  I would suggest you try implementing that and build your event list there.

Comment: I guess the part too I'm unclear on is how to build the event list there?

Comment: I put `NSLog` checks in `didFinishUserInfoTransfer` method, but neither were called.  I'd assume `didFinishUserInfoTransfer` is supposed to get called automatically just like `didReceiveUserInfo` though right?

Comment: I would assume the same thing, yeah.  Having said that, the code runs on the watch device I think, so maybe you're looking at the wrong console?  Maybe a breakpoint would be better, although I don't know how that works either.

Comment: Ok I'll check that out.  So on `let eventsList = Event.eventsListFromValues(receivedData)` how would I unwrap the two String values (tColor and Match) for use in the table?  I'm assuming thats where you are saying to construct the two arrays right?  Or am I understanding that wrong

Comment: I was wrong about the `session:didFinishUserInfoTransfer:error:`.  Apparently that gets called on the device side, not the watch side, so it won't be of use.  I'll revert that answer to not include that code.

Comment: The `eventsList` is an `Array` of your `Event` objects.  You could just enumerate it with a `for` loop, and each element of the enumeration will be an `Event` object that has your two properties.

Comment: I updated the code to remove that delegate method that was incorrect and replaced it with a for loop example.

Comment: Where would you be putting the for loop in the `didReceiveUserInfo` method example you gave (Before/Inside/After the `IF` statement?)?  And then once its there, is the idea to set event.eventTColor to something so that it can be used in the table?

Comment: You would want to put that code after you update the `receivedData` array, so that it creates an `Event` object from that data and not just whatever you had before.  I don't know what you want to do with those data values, but the actual values would be in `event.eventTColor` and `event.eventMatch` - you wouldn't want to set them, you'd want to use them.  We're straying fairly far off the question topic, perhaps asking a new question would be a good next step once you identify what you're trying to do.

Comment: Ok.  Basically just trying to show the `match` items in a standard WatchKit table.  Then use the `color` items related to their `match` items as that table cell/group background color.  Trying to get all of that set where I can start implementing my `setupTable` method.  Make sense in terms of where I'm going?

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like `eventsList` is the data you want to drive your `WatchKit` table with.  I haven't touched `WatchKit` yet, so I'm not much help on that part.

Comment: I know you're saying `event.eventMatch` holds what I'm looking for, so am I using the `for` loop to set the results of all of the `match`s to an array so I can use that array in my `setupTable` process? Or maybe you're saying in my `setupTable` I'm going to just use something like `event.eventMatchLabel.setText(event.eventMatch)`. I guess I'm not understanding how to get a list of `match`s to be used in a function outside `didReceiveUserInfo` ya know

Comment: You'll need `eventsList` in your `setupTable` function.  You can make a `var` property in your `class` for it, or you can just create it in the `setupTable` directly instead of `session:didReceiveUserInfo:` and just trigger your table to reload there (which I assume would call the `setupTable` function - but again I'm not familiar with `WatchKit`)

Comment: Have a quick code sample for doing the `var` property part or creating it in the `setupTable` (i can take care of the rest of the `setupTable` part after that)?  If you have some quick code you could put down that would be your best guess it would be much much appreciated!  I can tell what your talking about is the sort of thing I need to get me to the part where I can start doing the rest of the `setupTable`.

Comment: (Marking your answer regardless, will award you the bounty in 17 hours when it lets me)

Comment: It'd be the same as declaring the var property for `receivedData`.  It'd be something like `var eventsList = Array<Event>()` somewhere in your `InterfaceController`.  Then instead of `let eventsList = ...` later on, you'd just write `eventsList = ...`, which would assign it to the class property.

Comment: Quick question, when using `eventsList.count`  it returns null.  Is there a reason for that?  Do I have to loop through it for it to return a count?  Wondering because I'm trying to `setNumberOfRows` and can't get a count for anything.  Thanks!

Comment: `eventsList` in my example code above is not declared as an optional type and the `count` property of Swift arrays is also not an optional type.  As such, if your code is like the code above, it's actually not possible for `eventsList.count` to return `nil`.  My guess would be that you made a property on your `InterfaceController` and gave it an optional type (`[Event]!` or `[Event]?`).  If that's the case then you're trying to use it before it is set to a non-nil value.

Comment: The two properties I have are `var receivedData = Array<Dictionary<String, String>>()` per your code and `var eventsListSO = Array<Event>()` per your suggestion a few comments back if wanted to use it in a function to setup the table.  So what would be the best way to do a count on the code you suggested?

Comment: You could write `eventsListSO.count` and it should not be able to return a `nil` value, since the type of `eventsListSO` is not an optional and the count property on arrays is also not optional.

Comment: Yeah I tried `eventsListSO.count` too, and it still returned `(null)`.  I posted my `doTable` code above so you can see what I'm doing

Comment: If I try to use eventsList.SO in `doTable` I get nothing from the get go.  Can you help me out?